# Handling empty lines when folding by indentation

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, qt5

I am trying to write my own code folding algorithm that works using indentation.

Here's a snippet (Written in C++ using Qt5 framework)

```cpp
QList<QTextBlock> PlainTextEdit::getFoldableBlocks(QTextBlock rootBlock) {

    int indentation = rootBlock.text().length() - rootBlock.text().trimmed().length();
    QTextBlock block = rootBlock.next();
    QString blockText = block.text();
    QList<QTextBlock> foldableBlocks = {};
    QList<int> toRemove = {};


    while (block.isValid()) {
        int currentIndentation = block.text().length() - block.text().trimmed().length();

        if (currentIndentation == indentation && block.text().length() != 0) {
            foldableBlocks.append(block);
            break;
        } else {
            qDebug() << block.blockNumber() + 1;
            foldableBlocks.append(block);
        }

        block = block.next();

    }

    return foldableBlocks;
}
```

Now when using that algorithm on the snippet below:

```py
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):


        print("Hello world!")


class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello world")
```

Then the first class will be folded incorrectly since it thinks that the empty line means that the class is basically empty

The second class will be folded correctly because there are no empty lines between them.

How can I handle those lines correctly? I've been trying my own solutions for 2 days now and none of them worked and they were obviously too cluttered.

Comment: It might be easier to just remove multiple newlines from your input string. It looks like you just want to convert any sequence of n consecutive newlines to just one. There might be a primitive for that but writing a loop isn't that complicated.

Comment: This is for an IDE so if I removed the new lines using a for loop then the user would just reinsert them because everyone has their own coding style, some prefer new lines after function declarations and others don't